# How to read a dataset from a txt file in Python?

Tags: python, string, file, matrix, dataset

I have a dataset in this format:

[image: example data]

I need to import the data and work with it.

The main problem is that the first and the fourth columns are strings while the second and third columns are floats and ints, respectively.

I'd like to put the data in a matrix or at least obtain a list of each column's data.

I tried to read the whole dataset as a string but it's a mess:

```
f = open ( 'input.txt' , 'r')
l = [ map(str,line.split('\t')) for line in f ]
```

What could be a good solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can use pandas. They are great for reading csv files, tab delimited files etc. Pandas will almost all the time read the data type correctly and put them in an numpy array when accessed using rows/columns as demonstrated.

I used this tab delimited 'test.txt' file:

```
    bbbbffdd    434343  228 D 
    bbbWWWff    43545343    289 E
    ajkfbdafa   2345345 2312    F
```

Here is the pandas code. Your file will be read in a nice dataframe using one line in python. You can change the 'sep' value to anything else to suit your file.

```
    import pandas as pd
    X = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
```

Then try:

```
    print X
            0         1     2   3
    0   bbbbffdd    434343   228  D 
    1   bbbWWWff  43545343   289   E
    2  ajkfbdafa   2345345  2312   F

    print X[0]
    0     bbbbffdd
    1     bbbWWWff
    2    ajkfbdafa

    print X[2]
    0     228
    1     289
    2    2312

    print X[1][1:]
    1    43545343
    2     2345345
```

You can add column names as:

```
    X.columns = ['random_letters', 'number', 'simple_number', 'letter']
```

And then get the columns as:

```
    X['number'].values
    array([  434343, 43545343,  2345345])
```

Comment: That's pretty amazing. I was expecting that float and int would not be picked up, but nope, pandas detected it.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have CSV data (with tabs as the delimiter) so why not use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = [(col1, float(col2), int(col3), col4)
                for col1, col2, col3, col4 in reader]
```

`data` is a list of tuples containing the converted data (column 2 -> float, column 3 -> int). If data.csv contains (with tabs, not spaces):

```
thing1  5.005069    284 D
thing2  5.005049    142 D
thing3  5.005066    248 D
thing4  5.005037    124 D
```

`data` would contain :

```
[('thing1', 5.005069, 284, 'D'),
 ('thing2', 5.005049, 142, 'D'),
 ('thing3', 5.005066, 248, 'D'),
 ('thing4', 5.005037, 124, 'D')]
```

Comment: And if you use DictionaryReader and add column names in data file you can make it easier to parse data in python :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy.loadtxt("data.txt")` to read data as a list of rows

```
[[row1],[row2],[row3]...]
```

each row has elements of each column

```
[row1] = [col1, col2, col3, ...]
```

Use `dtype = string` to read each entry as string

You can convert corresponding values to integer, float, etc. with a for loop.

Reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 0):

split and transpose the list:

```
 with open ( 'in.txt' , 'r') as f: # use with to open your files, it close them automatically
    l = [x.split() for x in f]
    rows = [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
    rows[1],rows[2] = map(float,rows[1]),map(int,rows[2])
In [16]: rows
Out[16]: 
[['bbbbffdd', 'bbbWWWff', 'ajkfbdafa'],
 [434343.0, 43545343.0, 2345345.0],
 [228, 289, 2312],
 ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Comment: I think that OP actually wants the float and int columns converted.

Comment: @mhawke, there code suggests otherwise, either way it is trivial to do

Comment: The OP's code is almost correct; it's just that it doesn't convert to float or int (and there's a stray newline). Why would the OP ask this question if they just want strings?

Comment: @mhawke, the OP's code was not correct, all the items were in different lists. Not grouped together

Comment: For what it's worth (probably nothing) - OP said that either was acceptable: "I'd like to put them in a matrix or just to obtain an list for each culomn" (sic). You've provided a solution for the 2nd option. OP's code is for the 1st option. Either way I believe that he wants floats and ints in the appropriate columns.

Comment: well it is easy change the code to do either, it is actually much faster creating lists as above than  using pandas.

Comment: No argument with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to read in the data and convert those second and third columns to numeric types:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')

rows = []
for line in f:
    # Split on any whitespace (including tab characters)
    row = line.split()
    # Convert strings to numeric values:
    row[1] = float(row[1])
    row[2] = int(row[2])
    # Append to our list of lists:
    rows.append(row)

print rows
```

With the following `input.txt`:

```
string1 5.005069    284 D
string2 5.005049    142 D
string3 5.005066    284 D
string4 5.005037    124 D
```

It produces the following output:

```
[['string1', 5.005069, 284, 'D'], 
 ['string2', 5.005049, 142, 'D'], 
 ['string3', 5.005066, 284, 'D'], 
 ['string4', 5.005037, 124, 'D']]
```