# How to convert table into dictionary with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make ADFGVX cipher.
In the process, I need to convert a substitution table into a dictionary.

For example,

```
<Substitution table>
    A   D   F   G   V   X
A   T   J   B   1   5   V
D   7   4   9   M   G   K
F   Y   N   3   Z   8   F
G   X   D   L   A   U   E
V   R   6   2   H   S   O
X   C   P   Q   I   0   W
```

into

```
{'AA' : 'T', 'AD': 'J', 'AF' : 'B', 'AG' : '1' ...... 'XX' = 'W'}
```

Does anybody know how?

---

I had totally no idea before, however, thanks to the first comment I've written some (below). The table is .txt format and as you can see it has headers on the first row and the first column. But I don't know how to remove these and match the key and value properly.

```
    f = open(tablefile_location, 'r')
    subs_table = list()
    while True:
        line = f.readline()[1:]
        subs_table.append(line.rstrip().split('\t'))
        if not line: break
    print(subs_table)
    subs_dict = { R+C: subs_table[x][y] for x, R in enumerate(['A', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'V', 'X']) for y, C in enumerate(['A', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'V', 'X']) }
    print(subs_dict)
    f.close()
```

Comment: What data format is your substitution table? Is it a custom class? A list of lists?

Comment: Typing it out should work. You got started well; just continue where you left off.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of what you have tried and researched thus far

Comment: You could have a look at list-comprehensions for dictionaries. Something like  `{ R+C: table[x][y] for x, R in enumerate(['A','B','C']) for y, C in enumerate(['a', 'b']) }`

Answer (score 0):

This will vary based on how the data is accessed in your `<Substitution table>`.

One idea that may make it a bit easier to collect the dictionary is to use [comprehensions](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/comprehensions.html#dict-comprehensions). For example:

`{ R+C: table[x][y] for x, R in enumerate(['A','B','C']) for y, C in enumerate(['a', 'b']) }`

Would give you the dict:

`{'Aa': t[0][0], 'Ab': t[0][1], 'Ba': t[1][0], 'Bb': t[1][1], 'Ca': t[2][0], 'Cb': t[2][1]}`.

The `R+C: table[x][y]` part creates the `key: value` pairs - you could change them to extract data however your table needs. One for each element looped over in each loop (`for x in X` for every `for y in Y`). The `enumerate` call is used to give the loop index as well as the value (`for index, value in enumerate(Values)`).

Comment: I had totally no idea before, however, thanks to the your comment I've written some. But I'm still having trouble with how to remove these and match the key and value properly.

Comment: @SuperSonic maybe you could check some of the other questions on the site for inspiration, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013792/how-to-read-a-dataset-from-a-txt-file-in-python . Potentially I imagine that you would like to use the header row and column entries to create the key in the dictionary also. Personally I would read and split the first row as a first step, creating a list of column-headers, and then for every normal row just append the first value to a list of row-headers, while making a table[][] of the values.