# Reading specific data from a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file which is two columns of data with headers(the header is "x" and " x-y data"). How can I read only the second column from the forth line to the end of the file(in order to skip the headers)? I only need the numbers.
I need a simple solution as I need to use this code in ABAQUS scripting.
Here is my text file:

```
              X              XYData-201   

            0.                 0.         
            3.99845E-03        0.         
            7.98118E-03        0.         
           11.9483E-03         0.
```

Comment: we can help you, but stack overflow isn't a code writing service. We want to see you give it a try first! see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a dataset from a txt file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013792/how-to-read-a-dataset-from-a-txt-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn a string like

```
"            11.9483E-03         0.           "
```

into the list [0.011948, 0.0] by doing the following (assuming s is the above string)

```
map(float, s.split())
```

Broken down into steps:

- s.split() breaks a string down into an array of sub-strings by splitting at whitespace turning s in this example to ['11.9483E-03', '0.']
- map(float, s.split()) takes the array above and turns into the list [0.011948, 0.0] by converting every element into a float.

If you need just the number at the second column, you can just do:

```
float(s.split()[1])
```

So assuming the file is name blah.txt, to read all the numbers in the second column when they start from the fourth line onwards, you do:

```
 with open('blah.txt', 'r') as f:
     for i, line in enumerate(f):
         if i < 4:
             continue  # we are in line 1-3, skip
         print float(line.split()[1])
```

If you want a list of all the numbers in the second column, you can use a list comprehension:

```
 numbers = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in open('blah.txt', 'r').readlines()[4:]]
```

*(Note: The assumes you are working with Python 2.7, or else map will not return a list, and print will require parentheses)*